# Last added List element overwrtiting others

Tags: c#, windows, forms

```
    private List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
    Movie _movie;

    _movie = new Movie();
    movie.Title = "test2";
    _movie.Year = "1992";
    movies.Add(_movie);

   _movie = new Movie();
   _movie.Title = "test2";
   _movie.Year = "1992";
   movies.Add(_movie);

   _movie = new Movie();
   _movie.Title = "test3";
   _movie.Year = "1992";
   movies.Add(_movie);

   label8.Text = movies[0].toString();
   label9.Text = movies[1].toString();
   label10.Text = movies[2].toString();
```

Okay, so I'm making a little program to help me and my friends/girldfriend choose a film when we're bored. Obvious functionality includes adding a new film to the List. I've added the labels there for testing, because everytime I add movies to the List, the last one overwrites all the others.

I've looked at the few questions/threads I could find on this problem and I can't see how on earth all the objects are somehow referencing the same object. Could do with a bit of help.

Comment: Are you certain that above code is failing? Can you share the implementation of Movie class? BTW, first two movies has the same title.

Comment: How have you overridden the ToString Method , or your own tostring method Show that code

Comment: Can you paste all of your code?  This looks like pseudo code - on the ~5th line you just have "movie" with no underscore and near the end you call a lowercase toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
   label8.Text = movies[0].toString();
   label9.Text = movies[1].toString();
   label10.Text = movies[2].toString();
```

To:

```
   label8.Text = movies[0].Title;
   label9.Text = movies[1].Title;
   label10.Text = movies[2].Title;
```

The reason is that you are storing and accessing the `Movie` class `ToString()` doesn't know exactly how you want to print it out unless you override the string method.

You didn't explicitly say so I am not going to assume that you have overridden the ToString() method.  If you did, then you need to post that code and any other relevant code from your `Movie` class.

Comment: Well, I've realised the problem was completely stupid, I'd accidently made all my variables static... BUT, at least I've learned that I need to override ToString(), to toString().

Answer (score 0):

That code is fine, assuming you are just approximating what your code does (ignoring syntax errors). The problem is most likely in your custom Movie `ToString()` implementation.